# my javascript doesn't work in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a java script witch is work correctly in Firefox and IE,but it doesn't work in chrome!
I wanna to when i click on the button it shows me the table.If i use chrome and click on that it loads table,but i can't see whole table because its scroll doesn't work correctly.
this is my script:

```
function toggle_it(itemID) {
    if ((document.getElementById(itemID).style.display == 'none'))
    {
        document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'inline';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'none';
    }
}

<tr class="query-box">
    <td width="30%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><p align=right><a href="#" onClick="toggle_it('mytable id')"><img border="0" 
                                                                          src="mypicbutton.gif">&nbsp;More...</a>&nbsp;</p></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you really have a space in the id `'mytable id'`?  That could also be asking for problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the table's `display` to `inline`, but that's not the normal `display` for tables; the normal is `table`. However, to make your `toggle_it` work on any kind of element, set it to `''`, which will make it act as if you hadn't set a `display` at all, falling back to the default `display` for whatever kind of element it is:

```
function toggleIt(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if(element.style.display === 'none') {
        element.style.display = '';
    }else{
        element.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

<sup>As you can see, I also cleaned up the code a bit in other ways as well.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is the value returned by Chrome for `style.display`. Try the following:

```
function toggleIt (id) {
  var el = document.getElementById (id);
  el.style.display = el.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
}
```

By testing for equality to `none` this code should work regardless of the initial value of `style.display`